Need explanation how MarkLogic's search:suggest function work
I'm trying to use search:suggest function and during experiments a few questions came up.
So I have a database with 10 documents that contains only one property:
{
"title": "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?"
}

and in my query console I have a code sample from documentation
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $options := 
<search:options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
 <default-suggestion-source>
    <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" 
          type="xs:string" facet="true">
      <element ns="" name="title"/>
   </range>
 </default-suggestion-source>
</search:options>
return

So a few questions that came up that I can't get explanation for based on marklogic documentation:

Why when I try to search with search:suggest("of", $options) I got 0 results but search:suggest("*of", $options) returns something. (Results: "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?", "The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time", "The Unbearable Lightness of Being") Why wildcard at the beginning helps?

I have a document with title: "The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time" and I assumed that search:suggest("Curious", $options) will return me this document but it didn't happen. Adding space at the end or beginning of the word helps (search:suggest("Curious ", $options). Why is that? Why these spaces help?



looks like the documentation lacks information on some of the features: https://web.archive.org/web/20141018110650/https://docs.marklogic.com/search:suggest#search-options. Here you can find comment on partial phrases not mentioned anywhere else.

Your search options specify range as the suggestion source, so it will be using the title element range index lexicon as the source.
That title element's lexicon values are the complete string value of the element. You can see what the lexicon values are:
cts:element-values(xs:QName("title"), "", (), cts:true-query())

The search:suggest() with your options will be the equivalent of performing cts:element-value-match() with a trailing wildcard. search:suggest will "auto-magically" append * to the end of the first string value specified, and be looking for lexicon values that start with that value.
So, when you execute:
search:suggest(("of"), $options)

it is roughly the equivalent of:
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("title"), "of*")  

and when you execute:
search:suggest(("*of"), $options)

then it's roughly the equivalent of:
cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("title"), "*of*")

For your second query for "Curious" with either leading or trailing space, it winds up parsing the value as a search expression and applying a cts:word-query() for "Curious" as a filter query. Similarly, if you had specified "Dog Curious " (note the trailing space after Dog AND Curious), then it would apply two cts:word-query within a cts:and-query().
You can get an idea of what the implementation is doing, and what it produces by enabling diagnostic trace events and applying the "MarkLogic.DEBUG" trace event. When that trace event is enabled, INFO level messages will be written to the application server's <portNumber>_ErrorLog.txt. You can use that information to better understand how your search:suggest() $qtext parameter values have been parsed and used.
